# Trying to pass Velocity DI msgs to a Spring successView on a redirect

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, velocity

First time asking a question so be gentle :).  Also, I'm still getting used to the whole Spring MVC, Velocity DI thing but I'm getting the hang of it

I'm trying to pass velocity parms to a Spring successView page as follows:

Java:

```
model.put("actionResult", "codeTable.deleteSuccess");
 return new ModelAndView(this.getSuccessView(), model);
```

servlet:

```
<property name="successView">
      <value>redirect:/successPage.htm</value>
</property>
```

However, on the successPage.htm, there should be a Velocity message stating

> Record Deleted

but its not showing up. Other redirects I've tried:

`<value>redirect:/successPage.htm?</value>` // no message

`<value>redirect:/successPage.htm?value=*</value>` //system error

Thoughts appreciated.  Please advise if you need more info.

Edit:

Some other info:

**Using:**

- Spring 2.5.5
- Velocity 1.6
- Velocity-tools 1.4
- JRockit 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Found out what the problem was:

There was a "actionResult" getter missing from the viewSuccessPage method for the controller that was used for the successPage.htm

Thanks for all those who viewed it.  Hope this helps others.